# async calls in LoadState blocking the UI Thread

Tags: c#, microsoft-metro, winrt-xaml, windows-store-apps, async-await

In my Windows 8app i am overriding Page´s LoadState setting it async and use it to download and parse data in a Task i await. Afterwards i bind these data to a GridView.

Although my processing should be running async all ui is blocked during my processing on that Task.

```
public class Example
    {
        // ...
        protected override async void LoadState( . . . )
        {
            await Task.Run(() => downloadAndParseData());
            // Update the UI with results
        }

        private async Task downloadAndParseData()
        {
            // ...
        }
        // ...
    }
```

Has anyone an idea why that is and how i may be able to fix it?

Comment: Why do you use `Task.Run()` if `downloadAndParseData` already returns a task?

Comment: Could you edit your question to include short, but complete example of the problem? There could be something in `downloadAndParseData()` that causes blocking. Also, are you sure the problem is in this code and not somewhere else?

Comment: If your downloadAndParseData method is doing a lot of UI updates, this could make your UI appear "blocked"...

Comment: @NicoSchertler I followed the example on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh994635.aspx, following your question i guess it`s not necessary?

Comment: @PeterRitchie I do all UI updates afterwards. But I´l doublecheck.

Comment: @svick I would love to post more than this very general example. Unfortunaly its company project and there is actually a whole lot of downloading, parsing and db accesses in it. Could you give me an example of what could cause UI blocking inside of the async task?

Comment: @Konstantin You don't need to post the actual code, just some code that shows the issue you're having. Take the code you have, simplify it bit by bit until it's either simple enough to post here or until the problem no longer occurs, which means you found the bit that way causing the problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your constructive help guys! I found the issue in my case and as svick guessed there were operations in my processing that blocked the ui thread. We use SQLite and unfortunally made use of the non async methods. It´s working fine now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used  SQLite library and didnt made use of its async methods.

Therefore all db operations ended up blocking the ui thread.

I solved my issue by using the provided async methods of SQLite